# Error "Stack around the variable was corrupted" in array of pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, stack-corruption

I have a class `Piece` and class `Board`, which represent chess pieces and board. In the `Board` class, I have an array of 8*8 pointers of type `Piece`, which I expect to hold pointers from index 0 to 63.

However, I get an error in the code below:

> Stack around the variable 'chess_board' was corrupted

```
Piece* m_Board[8 * 8];

Board() {
    int i = 0;
    //Black pawns
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    m_Board[i] = new Rook(i++, 1);
    m_Board[i] = new Knight(i++, 1);
    m_Board[i] = new Bishop(i++, 1);
    m_Board[i] = new Queen(i++, 1);
    m_Board[i] = new King(i++, 1);
    m_Board[i] = new Bishop(i++, 1);
    m_Board[i] = new Knight(i++, 1);
    m_Board[i] = new Rook(i++, 1);
    //Black pieces
    for (i; i < 16; i++) {
        m_Board[i] = new Pawn(i, 1);
    }
    //Blank squares
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    for (i; i < 48; i++) {
        m_Board[i] = nullptr;
    }
    //White pawns
    for (i; i < 56; i++) {
        m_Board[i] = new Pawn(i, 0);
    }
    //White pieces
    m_Board[i] = new Rook(i++, 0);
    m_Board[i] = new Knight(i++, 0);
    m_Board[i] = new Bishop(i++, 0);
    m_Board[i] = new Queen(i++, 0);
    m_Board[i] = new King(i++, 0);
    m_Board[i] = new Bishop(i++, 0);
    m_Board[i] = new Knight(i++, 0);
    m_Board[i] = new Rook(i++, 0);
}
```

After some testing, I found that the error occurs at the last `m_Board[i] = new Rook(i++, 0);` line, where variable `i` goes from 63 to 64. If I change that line to `m_Board[i] = new Rook(i, 0);`, the error disappears.

I wonder what effect `i++` has, as I thought that `m_Board[i] = new Rook(i++, 0);` is similar to `m_Board[i] = new Rook(i, 0); i++`?

I only access to the 63th element of the array, and pass variable `i` to the constructor of a `Rook` object, after that variable `i` will increment by 1.

How does that generate an error?

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?  Things like `m_Board[i] = new Rook(i++, 1);` have unspecified behavior before C++17.

Comment: The kicker is when `m_Board[i]` gets the value of `i` with respect to when the `i++` takes effect is not well defined until C++17. After that you have a bomb every time. [Quoting cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) Point 20 says, *In every simple assignment expression E1=E2 and every compound assignment expression E1@=E2, every value computation and side-effect of E2 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E1*. `i++` is to the right of the = and will occur before `m_Board[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m_Board[i] = new Rook(i++, 0);` and `m_Board[i] = new Rook(i, 0); i++;` is not the same. These are two different sequence point.

To quote cpp reference

> A *sequence point* is a point in the execution sequence where **all side effects from the previous evaluations** in the sequence are **complete**, and no side effects of the subsequent evaluations started.

Also

> There is a sequence point at the end of each full expression (typically, at the semicolon).

```
a[i] = i++; // undefined behavior (until C++17)
```

Kindly have a look at the following articles:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order (Specially Sequence point rules section)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point